# Crawlee Puppeteer Error : Cannot destructure property 'pQuerySelector' of 'undefined'

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, crawlee

I am trying to debug a puppeteer crawler which has started throwing a strange error which says :

> INFO  PuppeteerCrawler: Processing products list page...  WARN
> PuppeteerCrawler: Reclaiming failed request back to the list or queue.
> **Cannot destructure property 'pQuerySelector' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.**

There is no **pQuerySelector** property being accessed in the code anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
export const router = createPuppeteerRouter();

router.use(async ({ page, proxyInfo, session, log }) => {
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    });
    log.info('Checking if the page is blocked...');
    const title = await page.title()
    log.info(`Page title: ${title}`);
    console.log(proxyInfo)
    page.cl
    if (title === 'Blocked') {
        session.retire();
    } else if (title === 'Not sure if blocked, might also be a connection error') {
        session.markBad();
    } else {
        // session.markGood() - this step is done automatically in PuppeteerCrawler.
    }
});

const pushData = async (data) => {
    data = data.map((product) => {
        return {
            ...product,
            productUrl: postProcessUrl(product.productUrl),
            currency: extractCurrency(product.currentPrice),
            currentPrice: extractNumericValue(product.currentPrice),
            soldItems: extractNumericValue(product.soldItems),
            week_number: weekNumber,
            date: currentDate.toDateString(),
        }
    });
    await Dataset.pushData(data);
}

router.addDefaultHandler(async ({ page, infiniteScroll, enqueueLinks, crawler, log }) => {
    log.info('Processing products list page...');
    
    await infiniteScroll({
        stopScrollCallback: async () => {
            
            const products = await page.$$('a.multi--container--1UZxxHY');
           
            const visibleProducts = await Promise.all(products.map(async (product) => {
                const isVisible = await product.isIntersectingViewport();
                return isVisible;
            }));
            return visibleProducts.some((isVisible) => isVisible);
        },
        waitForSecs: 10,
    });
    await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
    
    let productsCards = await page.$$('a.multi--container--1UZxxHY');
    
    let productsLength = productsCards.length;
    
    let category = page.url().split('/')[4];
    category = category_dict[category] ?? category;
    let subcategory = page.url().split('/')[5].split('.')[0];

    console.log('category: ', category, 'subcategory: ', subcategory);
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace so we can see which line throws?